# placing a box bottom, which can grow in height

Tags: html, css

I have a container where I should place my main picture, this is:"bigImg".
This must be at least min-height:230px.

In "bigImg I have added a holder for the image itself "holder" and now I 
I want the "holder" always positioned at the bottom" but then that "bigImg" can 
grow according to the image size (at the height).

[image]

```
<div class="leftSidebar">
    <div class="bigImg">
        <div class="holder">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#"><img src="http://s10.se/agv/img/product/34072.jpg" alt="glass" /></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end - bigImg -->
</div><!-- end - leftSiebar -->

.leftSidebar {
    float:left;
    width:428px;

    background:#ffff00;
    padding:0px 0px 3px 0px;
}
div.leftSidebar .bigImg {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    min-height:230px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
div.bigImg .holder {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;

    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#f00f00;
    padding:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
div.bigImg img {
    max-width:390px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/kcZhy/)

Comment: your image height(http://s10.se/agv/img/product/34072.jpg) is greater than your least min-height:230px.  So how can you set set it bottom. reduce height of image.

Comment: The height of the images will vary in range from 160px to 900px, and I put everything set min-height of 230px is to screen for it so I is positioning "holder" bottom, I get a margin to the top

Comment: Do you really need to put a position absolute on your .holder ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`

And use z-index on img and holder.

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/kcZhy/2/

Comment: not quite what I thought, I think, "" will grow in height when you have an image that is larger and start from the bottom with mini value 230px in height.

Comment: What will grow in height? the red box or what? The demo i posted shows that the red box now "grows" on how high your picture is. If you change the ing src to another picture and lets say you set padding-top: 4px on the ing css. You will see that the red box covers the img on top and bottom. So the hight on the red box is set by the img.

Comment: Okey, so if you want the red box to change its height after the img its done with the demo. Now I have made it little more clear, with padding-top 6px just so you can see that the red box changes the height. Click on the img to see changes. http://jsfiddle.net/kcZhy/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check - http://jsfiddle.net/kcZhy/7/

Bottom aligned, growing in height upward.

Your css looks messy :) multiple display, padding and positions for BigImg class.

```
.outerholder {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:bottom;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px dotted grey;
}
.holder {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
min-height: 1px;
border: 1px solid grey;
}
img {
height: 80px;   
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="outerholder">       
<div class="holder">
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#"><img src="http://s10.se/agv/img/product/34072.jpg" alt="glass" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```